# What is the correct available entropy on UNIX systems?

Tags: linux, random

I have three questions related to entropy on UNIX systems:

1. I check entropy on Linux using: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`. Is this the standard place with information about available entropy defined in POSIX?
2. What is the correct available I should expect? I heard that entropy should be equal or more than 100 and that there may be a problem if entropy is constantly below 100.
3. Is this entropy used by `/dev/random` or does it also has anything to do with `/dev/urandom`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/dev/random` is not standardized. POSIX doesn't provide any way of generating cryptographically secure random data and doesn't have any notion of entropy.

The Linux kernel's entropy calculation corresponds to an information-theoretic model of entropy which is not relevant to practical use. The only case where this is relevant is on a new device which has never had time to accumulate entropy (this includes live distributions; installed systems save their entropy from one boot to the next). Apart from this situation, there is always enough entropy, because entropy does not deplete. Since Linux's `/dev/random` blocks when it thinks it doesn't have enough entropy, use `/dev/urandom`, which never blocks. Using [`/dev/urandom` is good for everything including generating cryptographic keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939) (except, as mentioned above, on a freshly minted device).

In summary:

1. No, this is not standard.
2. You don't care.
3. [Use `/dev/urandom`](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/).

Many, but not all unix systems have `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random`. See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=/dev/random) for a more detailed discussion.